# Bind Size of Component

Tags: javafx, resize, components

Is it possible to bind a Size of a component to another Size?

For Example:

```
Label lblTest = new Label("This is a Test-Example");
TextField txtTest = new TextField("This is a really really really really long String");
```

Now I would like to get the same Size for booth Components, is it possible to bind their size ?

Is there a Function/Method like this?

`Label.getSizeProperty(Textfiled.getSize())`

That's a virtual example, but i need something that makes the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force the label to use its preferred size (as long as it's parent has enough space) with

```
lblTest.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
lblTest.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

Then bind the preferred size to the text field's size with

```
lblTest.prefWidthProperty().bind(txtTest.widthProperty());
lblTest.prefHeightProperty().bind(txtTest.heightProperty());
```

Comment: Thanks for this Example. But i need a little bit a other solution. I need the txtTest.widthProperty*0,88 as the Width Size... Is this also possible?

Comment: `lblTest.prefWidthProperty().bind(txtTest.widthProperty().multiply(0.88));`